# unable to use laracasts/Integrated in unit test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm currently trying out Unit Test on Laravel 5.5 new dev install. and have installed the extension using https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated

This is my TestCase.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests;
use Laracasts\Integrated\Extensions\Laravel as IntegrationTest;

abstract class TestCase extends IntegrationTest
{
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

This is the Error I get when i run phpunit

```
Fatal error: Access level to Laracasts\Integrated\Extensions\Traits\LaravelTestCase::get() must be public (as in class Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase)
```

in C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\laracasts\integrated\src\Extensions\Laravel.php on line 9

```
Call Stack:
    0.0010     348128   1. {main}() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP  13. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\tests\Feature\ExampleTest.php:8
    0.0550    1862640   2. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:53
PHP  14. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322
PHP  15. include() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:444
    0.0550    1867200   3. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:148
PHP  16. spl_autoload_call() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\tests\TestCase.php:7
    0.0550    1867200   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleArguments() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:159
PHP  17. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\tests\TestCase.php:7
    0.0670    2190488   5. PHPUnit\Util\Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:771
PHP  18. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322
PHP  19. include() C:\xampp2\htdocs\laradev\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:444
```

Please how can i resolve this issue because I am unable to use the visit(), see() and type() methods

This is my Test
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on github readme most of this is integrated in Laravel Core.

See [Laravel 5.5 Http Tests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/http-tests), if you need more you can use [Browser kit testing](https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing) or if you want browser testing use [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk).

Comment: okay so that means I dont have to extend the integrated class right, since the syntax and methods is now different

Comment: Correct, just follow linked manuals. For test in your screenshot first link is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Browser Tests (Laravel Dusk) as Bostjan said at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk.

It supports a wide variety of interactions with elements which includes clicking links, using forms, attaching files, keyboard/mouse operations and much more.

This is an Example from Dusk Documentation

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\User;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Chrome;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        ]);

        $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('email', $user->email)
                    ->type('password', 'secret')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/home');
        });
    }
}
```